# Android ActionBarActivity textview from custom cursor adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-actionbar, custom-cursor

I need help with following...
I have listview with actionbar(with textview) and listview is populated with custom cursor adapter.

I want to update textview on my actionbar on specific activity in custom cursor adapter class.
(when user types a number in different listrows I want the sum of those rows displayed on my actionbar)
Now, i have covered that operation, i just need to display that number on textview which is on actionbar.
How can I do that?

My custom cursor extends CursorAdapter, not actionbaractivity.
Can I somehow get actionbar textview in cursor adapter and set it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CursorAdapter` requires that you pass in a `Context` when you initialize it. If you want to update the `ActionBar` within your `CursorAdapter`, you could initialize an `ActionBar` object by casting `Activity` to the constructor's `Context`.

```
private final ActionBar mActionBar;

public YourAdapter (Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    mActionBar = ((Activity) context).getActionBar();
}
```